# Remote Database and Table creation using MySQL and accessing information using the JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I don't know if this question has been answered before but I could not find any answer so I am posting. If found duplicate I am really sorry and guide me to the original post.

I am trying to learn how to connect JAVA and MySQL so I would like to create a table remotely using MySQL and access the data present in them using Java.

As I am using the organization laptop I cannot install any software so I thought of creating a table in some online platform and accessing it using my Eclipse but I could not find any website which allows me to create a simple MySQL table.

- I tried AWS but here we have to provide Credit card information. I know the money won't be deducted unless I exceed the usage but still a bit skeptical.
- Same with other many websites where we have to provide the Credit card info.
  I thought of using PHPMyAdmin but need to install the xampp or wamp server.
- Thought of using the DOCKER but same issue. I need to install the DOCKER HUB as I am using Windows 10.

Is there any website where I can create a simple table and access the data remotely using Java?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/ will give you a free 5MB MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

## Digital Ocean

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing#managed-databases) will accept alternative payment methods, in addition to credit cards. This includes wire transfer, purchase orders, and ACH. See the FAQ on [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing#managed-databases).

Looks like they give you $100 credit start to with. I don’t know if this requires prepayment or not.

Digital Ocean [offers four database systems](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing#managed-databases) as a managed service: [Postgres](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), MySQL, MongoDB, and Redis.

Keep in mind that you **pay by the hour**. Their pricing for both MySQL and Postgres starts at USD $ 0.02232 per hour, less than **three cents per hour**. So you can spin up a new database, use it a while, and then discard. Their dashboard makes it quite easy to verify that you have no instances currently running.

I have used both the Postgres and MySQL services briefly. I do recommend those specifically, and Digital Ocean generally, because of their clean design and attention to **simplicity in all aspects** including naming, pricing, startup, admin, and documentation.

By the way, I recommend using [*Flyway*](https://flywaydb.org/) or *Liquibase* or some such [database migration tool](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) for automatically running a set of **SQL scripts** to furnish each new database.